# Проблема с записью в БД. Потоки, Java

Tags: java, база-данных, многопоточность, postgresql

Реализовал **паттерн** `Producer-Consumer`. 
Класс `Producer` производит изображения а `Consumer` записывает их в **БД**. 
Если в классе `Consumer` заменить код (который выполняет запись в **БД**) на код, который будет записывать эти изображения на диск, то все работает. 
Если проверить все построчно, то `preparedStatement.executeUpdate();` он просто пропускает и сразу же переходить в блок исключений `Exception`. Ни ошибки, ничего.

Вот тут реализовывается запись:

```
String id_tile;
int zoomLvl;
int x;
int y;
byte[] imageInByte;
String id_photo;
DataLoader dat = new DataLoader();

private boolean available = false;

public synchronized void get() throws IOException, SQLException {

    while (available == false) {
        try {
            wait();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        }
    }
    // метод, который записывает в БД (должен записывать)
    dat.insertToTiles(id_tile, zoomLvl, x, y, imageInByte, id_photo);

    available = false;
    notifyAll();
}

public synchronized void put(String id_tile, int zoomLvl, int i, int j,
               byte[] imageInByte, String id_photo) throws IOException {
    while (available == true) {
        try {
            wait();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        }
    }

    this.id_tile = id_tile;
    this.zoomLvl = zoomLvl;
    this.x = i;
    this.y = j;
    this.id_photo = id_photo;
    this.imageInByte = imageInByte;

    available = true;
    notifyAll();
}
```

Значения в параметрах проверял, все заполнены, равных `null` нету.

Вот сам метод записи:

```
public void insertToTiles(String id_tile, int zoom, int x, int y, 
                     byte[] image, String id_photo) throws SQLException {

    Connection conn = SingletonDBConnection.getConnection();
    PreparedStatement pstmt = null;

    try {

        String query = "insert into tiles(id_tile, zoom, x, y, image, id_photo) "+
                               "values(?,?,?,?,?,?)";
        pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(query);

        pstmt.setString(1, id_tile);
        pstmt.setInt(2, zoom);
        pstmt.setInt(3, x);
        pstmt.setInt(4, y);
        pstmt.setBytes(5, image);
        pstmt.setString(6, id_photo);

        pstmt.executeQuery();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Error !");
    }
}
```

Добавил `e.stacktrace` и выдало вот такую ошибку:

> org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: current transaction is
>   aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block  at
>   org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2270)
>     at
>   org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:1998)
>     at
>   org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:255)
>     at
>   org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.execute(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:570)
>     at
>   org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.executeWithFlags(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:420)
>     at
>   org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.executeQuery(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:305)     at DataLoader.insertToTiles(DataLoader.java:83)     at
>   TileLoader.get(TileLoader.java:26)    at Consumer.run(Consumer.java:21)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Comment: А стектрейс исключения какой? Выведите `e.printStackTrace()`.

Comment: Я в джаве всего лишь месяц ) не знал о таком. 
**ERROR: current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block**

Comment: Внутрь `catch(Exception e) {` допишите `e.printStackTrace();` и запустите снова. Добавьте в вопрос *самое первое сообщение* об ошибке, которое будет выдано (вместе с именами классов, номерами строк и т. д.)

Comment: Ошибку выше комментарием выслал. Сейчас добавлю в вопрос )

Comment: Заодно может пригодиться схема таблицы `tiles`. В psql-консоли можно набрать `\d tiles`.

Comment: Это точно самая первая из ошибок, которые выдаёт этот код?

Comment: Добавил полностью ошибку в вопрос!

Comment: вы пробовали `pstmt.close();` может поможет?

Comment: Помогло на самом деле **conn.setAutoCommit(true);** вот это, но ведь тогда транзакции как таковой не будет ?

Comment: Почему же не будет? Если она до этого была, то и потом будет. Просто вам не надо при такой конфигурации заботиться о её завершении.